# flutter android build error after upgrade on macos

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using MacOs to build flutter android app and it was working fine until I have upgraded flutter from 1.5 to 1.7.
I have not changed any configuration in build.gradle and everything is like before. except that now when I run flutter build apk --release it gives me this error:|

> - Error running Gradle: ProcessException: Process "/Users/mojtabaparvar/Desktop/projects/test/android/gradlew" exited
>     abnormally:
>
> > Configure project :app registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) registerResGeneratingTask
> >     is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
> >     registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
> >     registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) WARNING: API
> >     'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with
> >     'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'. It will be removed at the end of
> >     2019. For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance. To
> >     determine what is calling variant.getMergeAssets(), use
> >     -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace. WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is
> >     obsolete and has been replaced with
> >     'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'. It will be removed at
> >     the end of 2019. For more information, see
> >     https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance. To
> >     determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessResources(), use
> >     -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace.
> >
> > Configure project :shared_preferences
> >              ********************************************************* WARNING: This version of connectivity will break your Android build if
> >     it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
> >              See ... for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
> >              This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
> >              *********************************************************
>
> Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run
>   with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':shared_preferences'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':shared_preferences:classpath'.
>   >     Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.jar
>   >     Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.4.0).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.4.0/builder-3.4.0.jar
>   >     Could not find crash.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:26.4.0).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/26.4.0/crash-26.4.0.jar
>   >     Could not find sdk-common.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.4.0).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.4.0/sdk-common-26.4.0.jar
>   >     Could not find ddmlib.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.4.0).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/26.4.0/ddmlib-26.4.0.jar
>   >     Could not find sdklib.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:26.4.0).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/26.4.0/sdklib-26.4.0.jar
>   >     Could not find layoutlib-api.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:26.4.0).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/26.4.0/layoutlib-api-26.4.0.jar
>   >     Could not find dvlib.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:26.4.0).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/26.4.0/dvlib-26.4.0.jar
>   >     Could not find repository.jar (com.android.tools:repository:26.4.0).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/repository/26.4.0/repository-26.4.0.jar
>   >     Could not find common.jar (com.android.tools:common:26.4.0).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/common/26.4.0/common-26.4.0.jar
>   >     Could not find protos.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.4.0).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/26.4.0/protos-26.4.0.jar
>   >     Could not find builder-model.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:3.4.0).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/3.4.0/builder-model-3.4.0.jar
>   >     Could not find apkzlib.jar (com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:3.4.0).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apkzlib/3.4.0/apkzlib-3.4.0.jar
>   >     Could not find apksig.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:3.4.0).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/3.4.0/apksig-3.4.0.jar
>   >     Could not find annotations.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:26.4.0).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/26.4.0/annotations-26.4.0.jar
>   >     Could not find databinding-common.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:3.4.0).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/3.4.0/databinding-common-3.4.0.jar
>   >     Could not find baseLibrary.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.4.0).
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.4.0/baseLibrary-3.4.0.jar
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s   Command:
>   /Users/mojtabaparvar/Desktop/projects/test/android/gradlew
>   app:properties
>
> Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems one of your packages is not updated and it might cause dependency issues. Looks like shared_preferences. Try updating that package and see if it works. Also you might want to include androidX dependency in your android gradle. You can follow the guide here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Comment: I had added androidx and updated shared_preferences, still the same error